# How to aggregate data group by week in FlinkSQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

If I want aggregate data group by day, sql:

```
select
DATE_FORMAT(ctime, 'yyyyMMdd'),
count(*) as num
from event
group by DATE_FORMAT(ctime, 'yyyyMMdd');
```

how to aggregate data group by week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate by week using:

```sql
SELECT date_format(ctime,'YYYYw'),
       count(*) AS num
FROM event
GROUP BY date_format(ctime,'YYYYw')
```

Any format string that is compatible with Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is supported in the `date_format` function.